# Uploaded Images not re-sized to ( Thumbnail, Medium, and Large ) size

Tags: images

I have a WordPress site that was working perfect before moving to a new server, The problem is when I upload any image it uses the original size in all places in my website ( means no re-size for the image - Thumbnail, Medium, and Large), I use FTP to access the Upload folder and I found the original image only without (Thumbnail, Medium, and Large size).

I checked my Media Setting and its okay without any problem, I hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the GD PHP5 Library installed. Alternatively the image crop sizes are all bigger than the images you are trying to upload. WordPress skips over these if that is the case.

First check if you have GD installed and version. You can create a test.php file with this code below. Upload to your server and browse to the file via your browser to view the result.

```
 <?php
// Display your GD library info
$gdInfoArray = gd_info();
$version = $gdInfoArray["GD Version"];
echo "Your GD version is:".$version;
echo "<hr />";
foreach ($gdInfoArray as $key => $value) { 
   echo "$key | $value<br />"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried the code above and git this error :

Fatal error: Call to undefined function gd_info() in /home/sbrgroup/public_html/phpInfo.php on line 3

Comment: Ok looks like your GD library is not installed then. Double check, just replace test file with this and scan through and look to see if you can spot the GD modules, if not you will need to contact your hosting provider to enable these modules for you.
'code'<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>'

Comment: Please @Matt Use This code instead :

<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
}
else {
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
}
?>